# How to get my Debian server delisted from RBL

Tags: linux, debian, spam-prevention, spamassassin

My server running on Debian 7 (wheezy) was listed on an RBL (Realtime-Blackhole-List) for spamming email (twice).

I have changed root password, installed `spammassassin`, reconfigured `postfix` to require SMTP auth but after a while, the server IP is listed on an RBL again.

What are the steps to check the integrity of my server, as well as figuring out why it was listed on RBL?

I don't know what else to do so feel free to edit this question or requested more information.

Comment: 1. Does your server acts as NAT router? 2. Have you blocked all outgoing SMTP connections not from postfix?

Comment: "*I have changed root password*". Remove the root password, and use a SSH key to login. The best way to check the integrity of your server is to reinstall it from scratch. Is the server in some cloud provider, or is it your own hardware?

Comment: @AnFi:  No, this server is a standalone app. I have disabled SMTP outgoing connections via firewall. I also find out a compromised account which was abused to send out emails and disabled it.

Comment: @xenoid: disabling the root login is a good practice, indeed. I switched to SSH key login to avoid brute-force attack attempts

Comment: @DioPhungSo Could you make it the self accepted answer?  It is yet another possibility not to forget :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is recommended practice from my VPC provider:

1. Check /var/log/auth.log for suspicious login attempts: `tail /var/log/auth.log | grep "successfully"`
2. Disable root password login and switch to use SSH key. Also install `Fail2ban` to prevent brute-force attack.
3. Disable outgoing STMP port via firewall if email function is not needed
4. If email is enabled, try installing `spamassassin` and configured it.